# Компоновщик требует версию компилятора и Boost'а в имени lib-файла. fatal error LNK1104

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, lib

Так я устанавливаю Boost

```
b2 install optimization=speed variant=debug,release --layout=tagged --prefix=BOOST_DIR
```

Имена lib-файлов у меня выглядят так.

```
...
libboost_serialization-mt.lib
libboost_serialization-mt-gd.lib
...
```

При сборке проекта я получаю ошибку

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib'

В настройках проекта у меня нигде не указан этот lib-файл ни с каким именем, только его директория. Проект собирается, если я добавляю версию компилятора и буста в имя файла.
 Можно сделать, чтобы мне не приходилось переименовывать lib-файлы?